# Reach parent class methods from arraylist of subclasses

Tags: java, object, inheritance, arraylist, multiple-inheritance

I am trying to reach my parent class Car() variables and methods, from my ArrayList in main() of Objects Automobile(), Bus() which all inherit Car(). It gives me the opportunity to get the .Class and I know I can then compare if the class is Automobile or Bus and then do some operations, but I am actually trying to sort allInOne() ArrayList by getModel() Strings.

```
public class Car {
private String brand;
private String model;

public String getBrand(){
return brand;
}
public String getModel(){
return model;
}

}

public class Automobile extends Car {
int x;
Automobile(String brand, String model, int x){
super(brand, model);
this.x = x;
}
}

public class Bus extends Car {
int x;
Bus(String brand, String model, int x){
super(brand, model);
this.x = x;
}

main(){

Car first = new Automobile("brand1", "model1", 2);
Car second = new Bus("brand2", "model2", 3);

ArrayList<Object> allInOne = new ArrayList<Object>();

allInOne.add(first);
allInOne.add(second);

//here is the question part

allInOne.get(0).getBrand;

}
```

Comment: Why do you create an ArrayList<Object>, and not an ArrayList<Car>? And why do you post pseudo-code instead of actual code? If an expression is of type Object (like `allInOne.get(0)` is), you only have access to the Object's methods. If your list was a List<Car> and not a List<Object>, the expression `allInOne.get(0)` would be of type Car, and you would have access to the Car methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having Object List use `ArrayList<Car>`

```
ArrayList<Car> allInOne = new ArrayList<>();
```

then you can access all these methods:

```
allInOne.get(0).getBrand();
```

**OR**
If you want to stick to List of `Object` for some reason, then you can do this:

```
((Car) allInOne.get(0)).getBrand();
```

Comment: I changed my ArrayList<Object> to <Car> and now I can reach them. But when I will try to reach Automobile variable "x" I guess I will have to

<code>
if (allInOne.get(a).getClass() == Automobile.class) {
    Automobile into = (Automobile) allInOne.get(a);
    System.out.println("x= " + into.getX());
}
<code>

Comment: @Greeed Any time that you have to use `getClass()` or `instanceof` you are usually modeling your classes wrong. In this case, there is no need to do any of this; just use `Car into`.

Comment: @Greeed as you dont have any extra methods in `Automobile` and `Bus` so it wont be required to cast them explicitly unless you have different methods in these classes, and if thats the case you need to use `instanceof` as @chrylis mentioned

Answer (score 0):

When instantiating the List, change Car as reference type instead of Object so that you might use the methods/attributes inherited from Parent Class.

```
ArrayList<Car> allInOne = new ArrayList<Car>(); // Java 7    
ArrayList<Car> allInOne = new ArrayList<>(); // Java 8 it is not longer necessary to put reference type when instance an object.
```